# Hanging pictures in the rooms

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways to hang 13 different pictures in 7 numbered rooms are
>   there so that there is at least 1 picture in each room?

So I tried to look at this from, say, each picture's perspective. So we know seven pictures have to go to different room each. Thus, we have to select seven of the 13 and then multiply it by 7! so that we have any arrangement of rooms covered. After that, each of the remaining five can go to any of the rooms so we have 7 possibilities for each and thus it's $7^5$.

Overally, we'd get:
$${13\choose7}\cdot 7!\cdot 7^5$$

But is that right? I'm not so sure cause I haven't solved many of such problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  There are $7^{13}$ ways to hang them if you ignore the requirement of one picture per room.  Now we subtract the number of ways with them in six rooms-this is ${7 \choose 1}$ ways to choose the empty room times $6^{13}$ ways to distribute the pictures.  But now we have double subtracted the cases where they are in five rooms, so we need to add those back in once...

Comment: Why did we double subtract those? Didn't we only subtract the six rooms scenario?

Comment: If the pictures are in rooms ABCDF, they would all be in ABCDEF and the number of ways to do that would be subtracted as part of the "all in six".  They would also all be in ABCDFG, so they would be subtracted again.  We only wanted to subtract once, so now we add the ways to put them in five rooms.  Now you need to think about the cases where they are all in four rooms.  How many times were they added and how many times subtracted?